# Can I use the same branch instead of a new branch?

Tags: git

I develop on the development branch. Normally I then create my feature branches from the development branch. Like scenario 1:

**Scenario 1**

```
development -> featureA -> development -> megre featureA = COMPLETE 
// A few feature branches later I realise I need to do something in featureA 
development -> featureA_1 -> development -> megre featureA_1 = COMPLETE
```

But I also thought I could take the already existing featureA branch and bring it up to date.  Like in scenario 2.

**Scenario 2**

```
development -> featureA -> development -> megre featureA = COMPLETE 

// A few feature branches later I realise that I still have to do something in featureA 
develompment -> featureA 
-> merge development 
-> ..add new things ... 
-> development 
-> merge featureA_1
```

**Question:** Can scenario B cause problems?

Comment: ff-merge will not be possible (probably). Because of the merge, rebasing might not work smoothly either

Comment: Scenario 2 is fine as far as I can tell. And you'll be able to tell if it's going to be fine by this simple criterion: if merging development into featureA is a fast-forward merge, then it'll be fine. If not, then start from a new branch.

Comment: For what it's worth, in my development workflow, once I merge a branch, I delete it. So I wouldn't have featureA lying around anyway. Thus, when I came to create featureA_1, the name featureA would be free and I might reuse that name for the new branch.

Comment: @joanis You are of course absolutely right when you say that you delete the branch again after merging. that's what I do in other projects. In this project it's different (at least at the beginning) and that's why this question arises. Thanks to you!

Comment: @MaikLowrey A bit of an odd workflow, keeping the old feature branches, but if that's your workflow, it might not make sense to reuse the branch: once you fast-forward merge development back into featureA, then any information you might have had by keeping the featureA branch around after the merge will be lost, since it'll just look like it split off of development when featureA_1 started, instead of when featureA started. So, I still claim you won't run into problems per se, but instead it might defeat the purpose of keeping those branches after merging in the first place.

Comment: Makes no sense. The last line of scenario B is `merge featureA_1`. Where did `featureA_1` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to realize that to Git, branches—or really, branch *names*—are irrelevant and unimportant.  What matters in Git are the *commits*.  It's possible to use Git without using any branch names at all: it's just extremely inconvenient for humans to work this way.

Git finds commits by hash IDs.  The hash ID of a commit is, in effect, its "true name": see [the Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_name) and, if you don't mind getting lost in the TV-Tropes pages, [the TV trope "I Know Your True Name"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IKnowYourTrueName).  But hash IDs are large and ugly and impossible for humans to remember: can you tell `dcc0cd074f0c639a0df20461a301af6d45bd582e` from `dcc0a86f2f2f036b3a379f41a4b754f8bb73ed6b`, at a glance?  But if one of these is `master` right now, and one *was* `master` or some other name some time in the past, well, *those* are meaningful to humans.  So we *use* branch names.

A branch name, in Git, is a name with several particular properties.  *All* references in Git store one hash ID, so a branch name stores one hash ID.  What makes a branch name special is:

- its full name starts with `refs/heads/`: `dev` is short for `refs/heads/dev`, for instance;
- Git will allow you to be "on" a branch name: other names force what Git calls *detached HEAD* mode, requiring the `--detach` flag when using `git switch` and automatically detaching when using `git checkout`; and
- when you make a *new* commit *and* are "on" some branch, Git will *automatically write the new commit's hash ID into the branch name*.

It is this last property that makes branch names particularly useful: after `git checkout branch` or `git switch branch`, we're "on" that branch, and *new* commits automatically advance the branch name.  Without this feature, we'd be stuck writing down all our commit hash IDs just to be able to find them again, or something equally obnoxious (manual `git update-ref` of each name as we work, perhaps).

In any case, once you realize that the purpose of a branch name is simply to be able to *find commits*, many things that were mysterious about Git before, become much simpler.  If you visualize your repository as *commits*—connected with one-way, backwards-pointing arrows, so that each "child" commit remembers its parent or parents—you get a simple [Directed Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) like this:

```
          D <-E <-F
         /
A <-B <-C
         \
          G <-H
```

where `F` and `H` are the *latest* commits in two "branches" that comes together, or split apart, at commit `C`, depending on whether you traverse your commits "backwards" (Git-style) or "forwards" (human-style).  *Branch names* simply *locate specific commits:*

```
        D--E--F   <-- br1
       /
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        G--H   <-- br2
```

for instance, or maybe:

```
        D--E--F   <-- develop
       /
A--B--C--G--H   <-- master
```

Note that these are the *same graph*.  The fact that one graph has a name for commit `C`, and one doesn't, does not affect the *graph*.  Since Git is all about the commits and the graph—and not at all about *branch names*—these are basically the same repository, in terms of what Git would do anyway.  All we have to to to change the second one into the first is rename `develop` to `br1`, rename `master` to `br2`, and add a name `main` pointing to commit `C`.

That's probably not how *humans* will *intend* to use this, but that's what Git sees.  So questions like this:

> Can scenario B cause problems?

are really questions about whether *humans* will make certain mistakes.  I don't think anyone can really predict [human reliability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_reliability) properly, but if you know what kind of mistakes you personally make, you might be able to assess what will work best for *you specifically*.  That's not really a technical issue of the kind one can solve by grabbing a StackOverflow answer, though.